# How to create a list of integers to output from an IEnumerable interface

Tags: c#

I've been over the .NET documentation pretty throughly but have not managed to understand how to output a triple integer list or tuple, instead of just a single integer, with the `IEnumerable` method. I understand the role of  `IEnumerable` in C# but not the manipulations needed to convert the answers to an `IEnumerable` type and clear the below error. Actually, I'm not fully sure what this function (from a coding assignment) wants as an output type since most of the documentation and references online seem to focus only on single integer outputs.

```
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type '(int a, int b, int c)' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<(int a, int b, int c)>'
```

---

```
public static IEnumerable<(int a, int b, int c)> TripletsWithSum(int sum)
{
    for (int a = 1; a < sum; a++)
    {
        for (int b = a +1; b < sum; b++)
        {
            int c = sum - a - b;
            if ( a * a + b * b == c * c)
            {
                var final = (a,b,c);
                return final;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Look into using the `yield` keyword: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `return final;` to `yield return final;`

Then your function will be generating the triples one by one on demand (e.g. in a `foreach` loop, one triple will be generated per iteration).

This is called *lazy evaluation*. Your function doesn't return a collection, but a 'recipe' on how to get the next element. Your function execution will be suspended until the next element is needed and so on.

Please note that you can either use `return` or `yield return` in a function. **Never both**. So you have get rid of `return null`.

You should use `return` when you are transforming an existing `IEnumerable` (e.g `return Enumberable.Range(1,3).Select(number => number.ToString())`. If you  build `IEnumerable` from scratch you should use `yield return`;

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you code does but you need to use `yield` keyword and no need to return `null` after `for` loop:

```
public static IEnumerable<(int a, int b, int c)> TripletsWithSum(int sum)
{
    for (int a = 1; a < sum; a++)
    {
        for (int b = a +1; b < sum; b++)
        {
            int c = sum - a - b;
            if ( a * a + b * b == c * c)
            {
                var final = (a,b,c);
                yield return final;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution not involving yield:

```
public static IEnumerable<(int a, int b, int c)> TripletsWithSum(int sum)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, sum - 1)
                     .SelectMany(a => Enumerable.Range(a + 1, sum - a - 1)
                                                .Select(b => (a: a, b: b, c: sum - a - b)))
                     .Where(x => x.a * x.a + x.b * x.b == x.c * x.c);
}
```

Comment: Ah this is a LINQ solution? Since I eventually want to move in the direction of #F I studied this suggestion.